# Object disposable error in lazy loading

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I am using lazy loading in my project. But I'm getting IDisposable error in user object, since using disposed the context before lazy loading is completed.

So i've chosen eager loading. But many people suggested that eager loading will give performance issue when we include more than 3. But I need nearly 6 or 7 should be loaded before object disposed.

Now without eager loading I can't get the values in lazy loading. Now I'm so confused which one I follow ?

```
using(var context=new ContextEntity())
{
   aoContext.Users.Include("Address").Include("Person").Where(u => u.Id == userId).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of Lazy loading, Try to use Eager Loading if you are getting error.

Here I've given link for your Queries.
http://codingatilivedigitally.wordpress.com/2012/06/01/lazy-loading-vs-eager-loading/